# How to get total count from more table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to combine three reports. I want to take count in each tables (smr_trn_tsalesenquiry, smr_trn_treceivequotation, smr_trn_tsalesorder), total count from three tables and using where condition employee_gid from hrm_mst_temployee, group by all primary key from above three tables.

```
select count(*), 
(
   select count(x.enquiry_gid) 
   from smr_trn_tsalesenquiry x 
   where x.created_by=a.employee_gid
) as enquiry_count, 
(
   select count(y.quotation_gid) 
   from smr_trn_treceivequotation y 
   where y.created_by=a.employee_gid
) as quotation_count, 
(
   select count(z.salesorder_gid)
   from smr_trn_tsalesorder z 
   where z.created_by=a.employee_gid and z.salesorder_status not in('SO Amended','Cancelled','Rejected')
) as sales_count 
from hrm_mst_temployee a 
group by a.employee_gid;
```

Comment: Sounds good. Did you try anything too?

Comment: Yes, i tried this one, `select count(*), (select count(x.enquiry_gid) from smr_trn_tsalesenquiry x where x.created_by=a.employee_gid) as enquiry_count,
(select count(y.quotation_gid) from smr_trn_treceivequotation y where y.created_by=a.employee_gid) as quotation_count,
(select count(z.salesorder_gid)from smr_trn_tsalesorder z where z.created_by=a.employee_gid and z.salesorder_status
not in('SO Amended','Cancelled','Rejected')) as sales_count
from hrm_mst_temployee a group by a.employee_gid;`

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.  In particular, are you trying to get one row per employee or one row overall?  And, what is the problem with your query?

Comment: As a total you need to get the sum of `enquiry_count` + `quotation_count` + `sales_count`, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating scalar Function by passing employee_id and
return the grouped count from it.

This [link](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-functions-the-basics/) will help you to understand how to work with functions